# member function that is not const should only be constexpr if on C++14 or later

Tags: c++, c++14, c-preprocessor, constexpr, member-functions

In C++11, constexpr on a member function implies const. That was changed in C++14.

I have some code that has a member function that should be constexpr, but cannot be const, so I'd like it to be constexpr if compiled with std c++14 or later. One way to do this is:

```
class Foo {
#if _cplusplus >= 201402L
    constexpr
#endif
    int baz(const Bar& bar);
};
```

Is there a better way to express this, preferably without the preprocessor?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best way to do it would be to take advantage of the Feature-test Macros, as part of [SD-6](https://isocpp.org/std/standing-documents/sd-6-sg10-feature-test-recommendations). The change that `constexpr` member functions are not implicitly `const` is marked as `__cpp_constexpr` having value `201304`. So that should be your test:

```
class Foo {
#if __cpp_constexpr >= 201304L
    constexpr
#endif
    int baz(const Bar& bar);
};
```

Which if you do this for more than one member function, you probably want to generalize to:

```
#if __cpp_constexpr >= 201304L
#  define CONSTEXPR_MEM constexpr
#else
#  define CONSTEXPR_MEM
#endif

class Foo {
    CONSTEXPR_MEM int baz(const Bar& bar);
};
```

The way you present it in the question (using `__cplusplus`) is perfectly valid - the advantage of the feature-test macros is that different compiles adopt various features at different stages, so you can get a more granular, accurate test. Going forward, all the major vendors have agreed that SD-6 is the right direction and that will be the way to do things in the future.

Note that there is *no* way to express this without the preprocessor. There is no conditional `constexpr`. There is just `constexpr`.

Comment: I see. Would be cool if you could do constexpr(expression) like noexcept(expression)